# Padding after linebreak with pseudo element

Tags: css, line-breaks

I have a text that breaks to two lines which has a pseudo element ::before it. When broken to two lines the text does not align since it aligns with the pseudo element in the first row.
Any Idea how to make the text align?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgwbj.png)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could you please post a jsfiddle or at least your current HTML and CSS here to enable us debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple ways to get around this:

1. Create a div for the pseudoelement that is the 100% of the parent element, then use the next inline child div (height 100%) for the text.
2. Use position:absolute as seen here:

   ```
   li::before {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   padding-right: .3em;
   content: "\f00c";
   float: left;
   margin: 0 9px 0 0;
   ```

http://jsfiddle.net/1oauqvav/